# Display error messages from serverside through javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, ajax

I have 3 files in total. login.html - login.js - login.php

```
function login(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var epost = document.getElementById("epost").value;
        var passord = document.getElementById("passord").value;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'login.php',
            data: "epost=" + epost + "&passord=" + passord,
            success: function(result){
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Here is the PHP-file:

```
<?php

require 'db.php';
session_start();

if(!$_POST['epost'] || !$_POST['passord']){
    echo "Type in username and password";
}
else{
    $stmta = $dbo->prepare("SELECT * FROM kunde WHERE epost = ?");

    $stmta->execute(array($_POST['epost']));
    $login = $stmta->fetch();

    if(empty($login)){
        echo "User does not exist";
    }
    else {
        $passord_db = $login['passord'];    
        $passord = md5($_POST['passord']);      

        if($passord_db != $passord){            
            echo "Invalid password";
        }
        else{
            $active = $login['active'];     
            $epost = $login['epost'];       

            if($active == 0){
                echo "Activate your account ($epost) ";
            }
            else{
                $_SESSION['epost'] = $epost;
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

This may be a silly question, so I appologize in advance, But how can these error-messages be shown through the js-script instead of the PHP-script?

Comment: The variable `result` contains the `echo`'d text from PHP, so decide on how you want to show it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your javascript you have a `success` property with `function(result)` this variable `result` will contain any output printed from the php file. You can then use javascript to inject the output (error messages) anywhere you like in your html.